# Which exceptions should I handle?

Tags: exception

I am designing a WinForms application.

At the moment, all my exceptions are being logged at the UI level.

However, for none of them, do I do anything other than logging. Is this indicative of a bad design?

Furthermore, in one method (.NET's method execute a command on a windows service), it can throw exceptions of type Win32Exception and InvalidOperationException.

With an exception like FileNotFound, I could prompt the user to provide another file (although .NET has methods built-in to check for the file's existence), but with exceptions like the above, they are down to low-level problems with the machine, so these can only be logged really.

Is this the right way to go with deciding which exceptions to catch? Also, should I catch or throw ArgumentNullException? It indicates a problem with the code, right?

Comment: What are the reasons for the Win32 and InvalidOperation exceptions you mentioned? Depending on those they could be considered boneheaded, exogenous, vexing, or fatal.

Answer (score 4):

(I'll use [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s [taxonomy of exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) throughout the answer.)

If there is nothing you can do about it, then just log and bail out of the current operation, screen or the entire application, depending on the seriousness of the error. Just don't try to proceed in the face of **fatal exceptions**. In some extreme cases (like an `AccessViolationException`), just logging or even letting your finally blocks run may not be a good idea because you don't know what will happen if you run code in a corrupt process.

`FileNotFoundException` and other **exogenous exceptions** you should handle anyways. Even though you can check if a file exists beforehand, nothing prevents it from becoming inaccessible in between the check and its use. These exceptions depend on external conditions that you have no control over, so you should be prepared to handle them.

You should never catch `ArgumentNullException` or any other **boneheaded exceptions**. *If it hurts when you do that, don't do it.* If you pass a null argument when you shouldn't, then don't pass it. Fix the code so that it deals with the null reference beforehand.